# как задать div блоку фиксированное значения

Tags: html, css

Товарищи подскажите как задать фиксированное значения div блоку, при котором он не будет убегать от зависимости разрешения экрана. Я гуглил и постоянно встречал, `CSS3 Media Queries` но под каждый монитор прописывать стили... Это я буду только себя повторять

Как должно быть не зависимо от разрешения экрана:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как происходит уже на другом конечном устройстве с другим разрешением : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#front{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 95%;
    height: 520px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-image: url(images/Combined-Picture-of-Truck-Types_main.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.while_1{
    margin-left: 23.777em;
    margin-top: 20.1em;
    width: 69px;
    height: 73px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="front">
            <div id="Trigger_whiles_f">
                <div class="while_1" id="while1">
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Пробовал указывать `margin` в процентах но блок не двигался не вверх не в низ, а вот в `px` он давал свободу перемещения

Comment: а вы пробовали ширину блока указывать в процентах? width: 10%; и почитайте про свойство object-fit для img (там можно сделать так, чтобы картинка никогда не растягивалась, но нужно в html, a не css указывать загрузку картинки). может поможет)

Comment: Спасибо за направление, я уже решил проблему. Психанул переписал все по новой, только с `container` и все стало на свой места =)